# Identify columns that allow NULL but don't contain NULL

Tags: postgresql, migration, plsql

I'm working with a legacy database that never had any `FOREIGN KEY`s defined and not very many `NOT NULL` constraints, even where they are obviously applicable. I've been manually adding these in where the migrations are cheap and the applicability is obvious.

However, I'd really like a systematic way to identify some appropriate targets instead of stumbling around.

I'm wondering if it's possible to write a query (as slow as it might be) to run on a snapshot of the database that would identify every `table.column` which is *not* `NOT NULL` but which doesn't have any (or perhaps has very few `NULL`s.

I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/17688833/56690 which is kind of the inverse problem but I am not really familiar enough with this kind of meta-SQL to know how reasonable it is to accomplish what I'm hoping.

Answer (score 4):

I adapted the query from the linked answer in my question and have something I think works, but I'd prefer if it returned a table instead of just raising notices. I may improve it later but if I don't and anybody else does later, I'll switch the accepted answer. Ditto for any obvious performance improvements (though I understand this is likely to just be slow).

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   rec      record;
  _notnull  boolean;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN 
      SELECT format('SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM %s WHERE %I IS NULL;'
                   , c.oid::regclass, a.attname) AS qry_to_run
            ,c.oid::regclass AS tbl
            ,a.attname       AS col
      FROM   pg_namespace n 
      JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid 
      JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
      WHERE  n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'  -- exclude system, temp, toast tbls
      AND    c.relkind = 'r'
      AND    a.attnum > 0
      AND    a.attnotnull = FALSE
      AND    a.attisdropped = FALSE
   LOOP
      EXECUTE rec.qry_to_run INTO _notnull;

      IF _notnull THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table % has no NULLs in the NULLable field %'
                    , rec.tbl,rec.col;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Comment: Just declare a proper function with the same body, except that you return the text from it instead of raising the notice.  You can even replace the text with `ALTER TABLE` statements, which then you can just run.

Comment: @dezso ah that seems like a good approach. I won't `ALTER TABLE` directly because some of these tables run a bit hot and I'd want to evaluate whether the application writes any of these fields (even if very briefly) as NULL. The goal is to just rule out columns that _definitely_ have `NULL`s so I don't waste my time on them.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest solution:

```
analyse;

select
  sc.nspname,
  rl.relname,
  ar.attname,
  st.stanullfrac
from
  pg_statistic as st
    join pg_class rl on(rl.oid = st.starelid)
      join pg_namespace sc on (sc.oid = rl.relnamespace)
    join pg_attribute as ar on (ar.attrelid = st.starelid and ar.attnum = st.staattnum)

where
  sc.nspname in ('public', 'foo') and
  not ar.attnotnull;
```

Comment: In some cases, when `NULL`s are rare enough to not show up in the sample `ANALYSE` considers, this might lead to false positives.

Comment: @dezso You are right, statistic is not absolutely accurate. However, IMO, if nulls are rare enough, then the column should be considered as a candidate to making it as `not null`.

Comment: I don't have permission on the `pg_statistic` table in this environment so I'll have to load a snapshot of the database locally to test this, but in principle this sounds like a good approach. For my purposes, some false positives and false positives are acceptable anyway, as I'm just trying to focus my effort.